# How to access docker image layers on Mac OS X

Tags: docker

I would like to retrieve information about docker image layers, especially
about files that were used to create an image.
I am using `docker history --no-trunc` to retrieve information about particular image, e.g.:

```
~ docker history --no-trunc alpine:3.8 
IMAGE                                                                     CREATED             CREATED BY                                                                                          SIZE                COMMENT
sha256:3f53bb00af943dfdf815650be70c0fa7b426e56a66f5e3362b47a129d57d5991   6 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]                                                                  0B                  
<missing>                                                                 6 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:2ff00caea4e83dfade726ca47e3c795a1e9acb8ac24e392785c474ecf9a621f2 in /    4.41MB
```

I would like to get information about this file:
`file:2ff00caea4e83dfade726ca47e3c795a1e9acb8ac24e392785c474ecf9a621f2 in /`

How to find `2ff00caea4e83dfade726ca47e3c795a1e9acb8ac24e392785c474ecf9a621f2`?

P.S. I am aware that this layer was created using `FROM` but this is the same case when creating an image using `COPY` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the bashbrew manifests for all the official library images (the ones in the `_` namespace) in the [docker-library/official-images](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/blob/master/library/alpine) repository. From there, you can find the source repository for the images and tags. Here's the [manifest for alpine](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/blob/master/library/alpine).

For the OS images like [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/), the base layer is typically an archive of the entire OS filesystem. The file you referenced is the output of the [image_build()](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/build#L14) function in docker-alpine's build script for that version of Alpine Linux.

A handy tool for exploring image layers is [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive). You can install it using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) on macOS.

```
brew tap wagoodman/dive
brew install dive
```

And, then run it like so.

```
dive alpine:3.8
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted to achieve :)